# Understanding Docker networking on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v

I expected that my docker containers (wp, mysql) would have the IP of "Docker bridge" as gateway, but it was not the case. Please consider the network map I drew. The goal is to make corrections to it so it provides the core knowledge on how Docker networking works. Rectangles with question marks are not clear to me where or if they are relevant in Docker networking. The DockerNAT rectangle probably needs correcting.

[image: Docker network map on Windows 10]

ipconfig host DockerNAT
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT):

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
--
                                       2a02:1800:100::43:1
                                       195.130.131.3
                                       195.130.130.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

docker network inspect bridge

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "6205fbb4b3245c57252338beb9b1f8622e0b726b8084c1fded884c8920165937",
        "Created": "2018-12-01T09:47:14.4459709Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

docker inspect Wordpress container

```
    "Networks": {
        "docker-wordpress-xdebug-phpunit_default": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": [
                "dcbaf41e8ca5",
                "wordpress"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "6e35e027c2528f99b0123fa120776b53deef1d97526d1f95351931ed4538d94d",
            "EndpointID": "f9f1c37b4a19c112f4ec57432b3c960fdf072f5a4cf04df8d0be93582d07ad36",
            "Gateway": "172.22.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.22.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:03",
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
    }
```

docker inspect mysql container

```
           "Networks": {
            "docker-wordpress-xdebug-phpunit_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "db",
                    "a60591925cee"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "6e35e027c2528f99b0123fa120776b53deef1d97526d1f95351931ed4538d94d",
                "EndpointID": "0a630b183b04284bbc4cf258618815bb6a665c9e07863d9bfcc57aeac16e8ec2",
                "Gateway": "172.22.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.22.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
```